# Android kernel module compile error

Tags: android, kernel-module, android-kernel

Well. I am going to add an android kernel module.Here is how am I doing it.
First, I created a vuln directory under the /drives with these files in it.(Kconfig,Makefile,vuln.c)

The content of Kconfig is

```
config VULN
    tristate "vuln module"
    default y
    depends on MODULES
    help
        A vulnerable module
```

The content of Makefile is

```
obj-y += vuln.o
```

The vuln.c has nothing to do with this error so I am not going to paste the code here.

After all of this, I am going to change the Kconfig and Makefile in the drives directory.
I add this to the Kconfig.

```
source "drivers/vuln/Kconfig"
```

And this to the Makefile.

```
obj-y              += vuln/
```

Then I go to the goldfish directory and did.

```
make goldfish_armv7_defconfig && make -j8
```

It compiles well and in the vuln directory I got these files.
built-in.o modules.order vuln.o

But when I start the emulator using this kernel. I can't find the vuln device in the /dev. I don't know why.

I am using goldfish-3.4 kernel  and ubuntu18.04 with arm-eabi-4.8

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want code and error message to be in the question post (**as text**), not linked as images. Please, [edit] your question and your code and the error message into it. Both can be formatted with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: OK, I changed it.

Comment: Please, recheck which directory you actually use: `drivers` (already existed) or `drives` (probably, created by you).

Comment: Thanks. I changed that and it compiled successfully. But now, I realized I can't find the device in /dev. Do you know why? I changed the question, can you take a look?

Comment: I don't know about the warning `unwinding may not work because EXIDX ...`, but you may try to google it. BTW, when add your code into the question, please, copy-paste it instead of typing manually. You still have a typo in line `source "drivres/vuln/Kconfig"`.

Comment: Yeah. It won't produce warning now since I used arm-eabi-4.8 as the compiler. But the vuln still won't show up under the /dev :(